# Automatically add javadoc when Generating methods

Tags: intellij-idea

If I press Alt + Insert to generate constructors, getters,setters, etc, I want IntelliJ to also generate a javadoc that has all the @return and @param entries there. Is there a way to adjust how the Generation feature works?

I know I can add `/**` above the method and it generates it, but if I have multiple methods I generated, I don't want to have to do this on each one.

I'm on IntelliJ 2016.3 Ultimate

Answer (score 1):

There is a request for that:

- [IDEABKL-4910](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-4910) Javadocs for 
  gettes/setters

Since it's in the backlog project, I doubt that it will be implemented any time soon, especially considering the following comment:

> We have a strong feeling that meaningless documentation is worse than
>   no documentation at all, and because of that, we do not plan to
>   implement features for generating meaningless documentation.